# What is a word for an "inverse panorama"?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, photography

Specifically, what is a word for the action of taking several pictures of an object from multiple, regular angles and has the same connotation as "panorama" (where you would take multiple pictures of an environment, stay in a fixed location and rotate). The end result of this action would be a collection of photos that show off every angle of said object. Any ideas?

To be a little clearer: in this case, the camera would remain fixed and the object would rotate.

Result Example: [[Home Depot Website](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Miracle-Gro-Nature-s-Care-3-in-1-Insect-Disease-and-Mite-Control-077611005/205725460)] (click on ' 360° ');

Comment: Sounds like *3D mapping*.

Comment: As @bib said but It's also still a sort of panorama. Often called 360 panorama.See for example http://www.airpano.com/  . The definition of panorama does not specify any fixed point of view. Panorama is just a stitching of several pictures as to appear continuous.

Comment: @Victor can you edit your question to include some links to examples of the sort of photos you're referring to?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a *composite photograph.*  I know this term primarily from images published by NASA and other space agencies from their various probes.  (If this is what you are thinking of I can try to form it into an answer.)

Comment: You say you're looking for a word for an action, like panorama. But panorama is not the word for an action, it's the word for a type of image. Which are you looking for?

Comment: The OED ascribes three principal meanings to the word *panorama*. However two of them provide very broad senses: *2. A complete and comprehensive survey or presentation of a subject* *3. An unbroken view of the whole region surrounding an observer.*. So there is nothing here to say that it necessarily has to be a picture taken from a fixed location. The word *Panorama* is actually better known and far more often used in the UK of a BBC TV Current Affairs programme, now in its seventh decade. "Panorama - Your Window on the World" - its titles used to say.

Answer (score 0):

A non-composited collection of related images is usually called a **multi-image**.

> To apply this methodology to stereo matching, we compute the depth map
>   using a pair of images selected from a larger, multi-image ...

Vision Algorithms: Theory and Practice: International Workshop on Vision ...
edited by Bill Triggs, Andrew Zisserman, Richard Szeliski

The process is termed **image capture** if it is feeding a 3D conversion proggy.